# RTF Display some words as single unit (not as multiple chars)?

Tags: richtextbox, rtf

How can I make a random word like `"hello world"` appear and be like **one unit** ? So that I can't copy "hello" without copying "hello world" as a whole ?

It should not be like 11 characters but like 1 wide character/block. Maybe a box or something table-like.

*(I'm programming C# and using the RichTextBox)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, you can use a TextBlock or a Run. If you are using winforms, you can select the two words when any is clicked.